# Installing Ubuntu on MacBook Pro

Tags: system-installation, macbook-pro

I'm trying to install Ubuntu desktop on my MacBook Pro. I've created the USB installer but it freezes on the Ubuntu installer loading screen:

[Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lmRbt.png)

At first the dots are blinking, showing that it's doing something, but after a few sec they stay orange.

I used this [tutorial](http://www.makeuseof.com/tag/install-linux-macbook-pro/).

My MacBook Pro is a Mid 2009 model.

Anyone an idea why it keeps doing that? Am I missing something?

I have also tried the Mac Ubuntu image, but that one won't even show up as bootable disk. I also tried the rEFInd boot manager.

Comment: Can you try the steps here? https://levlaz.org/install-ubuntu-14-04-on-macbook-air-11-61/ I have done this on tons of different macbooks this year and works flawlessly every time.

Comment: There seem to be a lot issues with the Ubuntu installer on MacBooks with a GeForce 9400M. Any idea about how to solve that? The installer freezes after "Stopping Restore Sound Card State". My guess is that it's starting Xorg after that, which is causing the freeze.

Answer (score 1):

2018-11-02
My recent experience installing ubuntu 18.04 on same MacBook Pro mid 2009 ( MBP 5.5 ) that had ubuntu 14.04 and for THOSE WHO HAPPENS TO HAVE A BEAUTIFULL USELESS, WOTHLESS MacBook Pro that sits around doing nothing because Mountain Lion is overpass not suppoorted and dead!
My recipe is if you DO NOT GIVE UP AND ARE VERY PERSISTENT.
I have to say It is becoming tedious or I am getting older....
First let us be clear, The ''refind'' approach did not work before and not this time again for me on this Mac Book Pro and not on a more recent Mac Boo Pro with intel i5! and not with my older big MacBook Pro 2008 with 2 Zeon cpu totalling 4 cores.
On the MAc BOOk Pro mid-2009 I tried the DVD approach and pressing C key - No success it is always rejeted.
I tried pressing the ''alt-option'' key - not much luck it would stop after starting to read the 18.04.iso DVD, then engaged in a reject... and same with a usb flash drive alone.

The approach I used that was succesfull...
I got get rid of refind , insert the DVD + the usb flash drive all at same time.
Restart pressing ''Alt-option'' key + power on switch.
I Held on, cause it takes time. Don't let off the ''alt-option'' until you see the new choice showing ''windows'' and the ''yellow usb drive''. 
Select the new yellow usb drive. It should go on... with the installaton process.

The first pitfall I had to face was at the time of selecting the city/country.
My choice was Montreal,Qc ... but  that never stayed selected and it always moved  to Toronto, On ... Why? unknown.... After reselecting over 20 times I decided to keep Toronto and go on... 
Then came another problem with language. In all previous installations since Ubuntu 6.XX (over 10 years or so) I always seleced English US as the language
and things would roll on to install. This time, NO it cut off and died out. I had to restart the whole process from the beginning. I found out it was a NO NO.

By luck or chance after 5-6 times, I decide to selected ''English Canadian'',''Canadian Multilingual'' and regional ''Canadian French''. That is the only way it proceeded to install. I selected the minimal, with no downloads while installing. When I rebooted I could connect to update and dist-upgrade + Install all the other apps as I liked to choose.
There must be some bugs in this new vesion 18.04-1 and I pass my experience because many may have tried to install a much better OS on these Apple products the company wants us to throw away .Apple want us to Keep up piling the waste on the planet...and give them money

Denis Gaulin

Answer (score 0):

I have just completed installing Ubuntu 14.04LTS on the same version, mid-2009 MacBook Pro.

The way I did it. - I followed Rottlatl advise posted on this post and started first installing Refit on my Mac.
Then I closed and booted from the DVD ( holding down  Alt option key to boot from the DVD or a USB key.
My Ubuntu 14.04 version is the regular one.  Everything when fine to my amazement. I was so surprised because I had tried many other methods and nothing worked.
Now I have to say that My purpose was to replace 100% Mac Elcaptan because I hate to be told that I have to accept and install ITune ++. Also if you are not alert they want your credit card and ++++  To me ElCaptan was nothing of a pleasant experience. I did not see anything that I would miss. It is a regular software and below par for Mac.
Going back to the installation process.  I selected Ubuntu 14.04 LVM ( logical volume Management) formatting installation and I like this approach.

Remember that this is a 100% replacement.  It is not a dual or triple boot installation.
If you want dual boot it might be advisable to use Refind because I tried it and it worked.