# Install Ubuntu Bionic 18.04 on MacBook Pro 2018?

Tags: boot, system-installation, 18.04, mac, macbook-pro

I've got a 2018 MacBook Pro 13" with Touch Bar and would like to install Ubuntu 18.04 Bionic (or Kubuntu) on it.

It boots fine from the USB stick (created per Ubuntu Tutorial "[Create bootable USB stick on macOS](https://tutorials.ubuntu.com/tutorial/tutorial-create-a-usb-stick-on-macos)"). **But in Ubuntu (or Kubuntu), neither the keyboard nor the touchpad work** ;-(

I've read the post [Installing Ubuntu on MacBook Pro](https://askubuntu.com/questions/643709/installing-ubuntu-on-macbook-pro) on ask ubuntu.

A bit later, I found the Gist "[0 Linux-On-MBP-Late-2016.md](https://gist.github.com/roadrunner2/1289542a748d9a104e7baec6a92f9cd7)". According to this, Keyboard and Touchpad just don't work during installation. "*Fine*"…

I now managed to repartition the mac's disk and install macOS High Sierra and Kubuntu on the system. **But now I'm stuck at the Grub prompt :(**

Would anyone maybe have a definitive guide? ;)

Comment: I recommend that you install it on a virtual machine like Virtualbox and enjoy using both macOS and Linux beside each other. It has an unpainful process and boots very fast!

Comment: We had a similar issue today in my class. The issue was that we add a standard keyboard instead of a macintosh  keyboard during installation

Comment: Have you tried this tutorial https://nixaid.com/linux-on-macbookpro/?

Comment: Still no luck on 18.10 today

Answer (score 5):

Getting the internal trackpad and keyboard to work with the 2018 Macbook pro is the least of your concern really.
There are no drivers for the Apple SSD controller yet. So regardless of that fact, it won't let you install anything...

Comment: this is no longer true, and given the wording of the question, maybe was not true at time of answering?

Comment: Just tried to install 18.04 on MBP 15 touchbar and the installer can't detect the SSD which is the reason I landed on this post so i guess. It's still not possible yet.

Answer (score 1):

You can't install, the T2 Chip inside Macbook Pro, prevent you from writing on encrypted internal drive.

Your only option is to use Virtualbox or similar software

Answer (score 0):

I can think of one ways around missing keyboard support during installation and until you can boot the system properly and install suitable input device drivers:

**Use an external (USB) keyboard and (optionally) mouse.**

Once you have that set up you can probe further and refer to other topics on this site (or elsewhere) or ask your own questions.