# Install Kubuntu 18.04 on MacBook Pro 2018

Tags: 18.04, kubuntu, mac, macbook-pro

So I ran into the same problems described here: [Install Ubuntu Bionic 18.04 on MacBook Pro 2018?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1052373/install-ubuntu-bionic-18-04-on-macbook-pro-2018)
Just that I've got the 15''.

Booting works (after I disabled **Secure Boot** and allowing to boot from any external device with any bootable system in the *System Recovery*)

I'm currently stuck at the repartitioning of my drive because *ubi-partman keeps crashing with a 141 error code*.
I installed gparted on the Kubuntu live system to check the drives and it seems that only the USB-drive from which Kubuntu is running is detected. The 100 GB Mac Partition nor the 900 GB FAT formatted partition I want to use for the installation are listed anywhere.
I tried installing **e2fsprogs** on MacOs and formatting the Linux Partition with ext4, but I get the same result.

What else can I try?

Answer (score 0):

**I gave up on it as it doesn't seem to be a viable thing to do.**

As pointed out in an answer that I got asking on reddit:

https://www.reddit.com/r/macbook/comments/9s3lqf/installing_linux_on_new_macbook_pro_2018/
https://www.reddit.com/r/Ubuntu/comments/9s3oxt/installing_linux_on_new_2018_macbook_pro/

> Most of your hardware is not supported, yet (by the kernel) and definitely not optimized for battery life.
>   You can get it running without problems, but there'll be no audio, touchbar and 2 hours battery max.

That's backed up by the fact that I can't use my keyboard nor touchpad when at the installer-stage. Don't know whether they would work when K/Ubuntu is installed since I never got that far.