# Linux installation can't detect hard drive on Macbook Pro touch bar

Tags: system-installation, macbook-pro

I have been trying to install either Ubuntu 18.04 or Kali on my Macbook Pro 15 with touch bar purchased late 2018.

During the installation, the installer can only see the USB drive where the installer is running from. But it doesn't detect the internal hard drive.

I have tried GParted from live Kali or `fdisk -l` from both Kali and Ubuntu. They couldn't detect the internal drive either.

Also tried to install rEFInd and can boot from it but still the installer can't detect the drive.

I have tried to create a partition with EX-FAT or MS-DOS FAT from Disk Utility, and still no joy.

I have searched the net and i have seen similar posts but those seem to be for the same problem with other Windows machines and the solutions I have tried so far didn't work for me.

Some suggested to change AHCI mode in bios but MBP doesn't seem to have that.

My MBP already has bootcamp running with Windows 10 on a partition.

Please suggest me what I am doing wrong if it's possible to install Linux on MBP at all.

Comment: https://askubuntu.com/q/1052373/459652 among others.

Comment: thanks for the comment, so the answer is it's not possbile i guess? @jdv

Comment: It's hard to say what's possible but any info we collect on the problem should probably be captured in what looks like a duplicate question.

Comment: yeah, i guess it's good to link similar issues. i did an effort to look for a solution before i asked though.